# when i tried to make make for zlib-1.2.7 i found error 127

Tags: linux, shell

i want to do make fo zlib-1.2.7 and found the next error:

```
make 
gcc -O3  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -c -o example.o test/example.c
make: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:144: example.o] Error 127
[lamiaa@fedora zlib-1.2.7]$ make check 
gcc -O3  -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -c -o example.o test/example.c
make: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:144: example.o] Error 127
```

i need to fix this problem

Comment: What does `type gcc` (in bash, `which gcc` in zsh, `command -v gcc` in baseline POSIX sh) return? This implies that either you don't have a correctly installed compiler, or you have something earlier in your PATH that conflicts with your attempts to _start_ any such correctly-installed compiler you may otherwise have.

Comment: Also, try running `gcc --version`. If you can't do that successfully, you have problems that have nothing to do with zlib or make.